# custom module disable/enable not working in admin - Magento

Tags: xml, magento, layout

I am creating a custom module named 'standingorders' inside namespace Stallioni

My app/etc/modules/Stallioni_Standingorders.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stallioni_Standingorders>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
                <Mage_Checkout/>
                <Mage_Customer />
                <Mage_Sales />
                <Mage_Adminhtml/>
            </depends>
            </Stallioni_Standingorders>
   </modules>
</config>
```

My app/code/local/Stallioni/Standingorders/etc/config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stallioni_Standingorders>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Stallioni_Standingorders>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <standingorders>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Stallioni_Standingorders</module>
                    <frontName>standingorders</frontName>
                </args>
            </standingorders>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <standingorders>
                    <file>standingorders.xml</file>
                </standingorders>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <standingorders>
                <class>Stallioni_Standingorders_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>standingorders_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </standingorders>
            <standingorders_mysql4>
                <class>Stallioni_Standingorders_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <standingorders>
                        <table>standingorders</table>
                    </standingorders>
                </entities>
            </standingorders_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <standingorders_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Stallioni_Standingorders</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </standingorders_setup>
            <standingorders_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </standingorders_write>
            <standingorders_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </standingorders_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <standingorders>
                <class>Stallioni_Standingorders_Block</class>
            </standingorders>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <standingorders>
                <class>Stallioni_Standingorders_Helper</class>
            </standingorders>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

In default/default/template/standingorders/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml i have overriden the base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

My layout/standingorders.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"> 
<standingorders_index_index>
<reference name="content">
<block type="standingorders/standingorders" name="standingorders" />
</reference>
</standingorders_index_index>
<checkout_cart_index> 
<reference name="head">
<action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params></params></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name></action>
<block type="core/html_calendar" name="head.calendar" as="calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"></block>
</reference>
<reference name="checkout.cart">
<action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
<template>standingorders/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template>
</action>
</reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
<standingorders_ajax_index>
    <block type="standingorders/standingorders" name="root" output="toHtml" template="standingorders/checkout/cart/item/call.php" />
  </standingorders_ajax_index>
 <checkout_onepage_review>
 <reference>
  <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
  <template>standingorders/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template>
  </action>
  </reference>
 </checkout_onepage_review>
</layout>
```

My problem is when i disable Stallioni_Standingorders in Configuration ->Advanced tab, the module not getting disabled. It showing the customization i have done in default.phtml. I have cleared the cache but still problem occurs.. Any one help!

Comment: Anyone please help.. Stackoverflow made me lonely:(

Comment: Try Disabling the cache.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Shatir, i tried it but still now no result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. I did overriding the block in my module. I have overidden Standingorders/Block/Standingorders/Cart/Item/Renderer.